# Somehow appending another list changes a different list (Python)

Tags: python

When I run this code I get an error that the list index is out of range because the index of dataLoopVar is out of the range of the trueDataList, even though this should not be possible. Somehow dataLoopVar is changing the value of trueDataList when I'm appending the other lists?

The Code:

```
dataLoopVar = 0
dataLoopMax = len(trueDataList)

while dataLoopVar <= dataLoopMax:
    studentList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
    districtList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
    lunchList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
    sportList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
    statusList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
    nList.append (trueDataList[dataLoopVar]) 
    dataLoopVar = dataLoopVar + 1
```

Comment: Please try simplifying the code to zero in on which parts cause the error, instead of chucking the whole thing on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically**

```
dataLoopMax = len(trueDataList) - 1    # It should work now
```

The problem with your code is the `len()` function:

`len()` returns the number of elements in a function -> `len([1])` would return `1` whereas since list elements start from 0, we have a problem (shown below)

**Simplified** version of what's going wrong:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
num_elem = len(a_list)
print(f"Element number of a_list is {num_elem}")

print(a_list[num_elem]) # List out of bounds error
```

**Fix for error**

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
num_elem = len(a_list) - 1
print(f"Element number of a_list is {num_elem + 1}")

print(a_list[num_elem]) # Works
```